# Why am i unable to infer the actual types in tuple?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have the following factory Class:

```
class ElementFinder {
  doSomething(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

interface Cell {
  getKey(): string;
}

interface CellFactory<T extends Cell[]> {
  createCellForIndex<I extends number>(index: I, elementFinder: ElementFinder): T[I]
}

class CellElementFactory<T extends Cell[]> implements CellFactory<T> {
  constructor(private cells: [...{ [I in keyof T]: new (elementFinder: ElementFinder) => T[I] }]) { }

  createCellForIndex<I extends number>(index: I, elementFinder: ElementFinder): T[I] {
    const Ctor = this.cells[index];
    return new Ctor(elementFinder);
  }
}
```

Any Class that's passed to the factory's constructor within an Array, must implement the `Cell` interface and also have a constructor signature that's compatible with `CellConstructor`.

I'm able to create a factory instance and the return types are correctly inferred:

```
class CellA implements Cell {
  constructor(elementFinder: ElementFinder) { }
  getKey(): string {
    return 'A'
  }
}

class CellB implements Cell {
  constructor(elementFinder: ElementFinder) { }
  getKey(): string {
    return 'B'
  }
}

class CellC implements Cell {
  constructor(element: ElementFinder) { }
  getKey(): string {
    return 'C'
  }
}


const cellFactory = new CellElementFactory([CellA, CellB, CellC, CellB, CellC, CellA]);
const cell1 = cellFactory.createCellForIndex(0, new ElementFinder()); // CellA
const cell2 = cellFactory.createCellForIndex(1, new ElementFinder()); // CellB
const cell3 = cellFactory.createCellForIndex(2, new ElementFinder()); // CellC
const cell4 = cellFactory.createCellForIndex(3, new ElementFinder()); // CellB
const cell5 = cellFactory.createCellForIndex(4, new ElementFinder()); // CellC
const cell6 = cellFactory.createCellForIndex(5, new ElementFinder()); // CellA
```

**Problem**

However, I have a class that uses the factory instance and i'd like to be able to infer the cell types tuple from the factory, but i've not been able to get it to work.

```
class CellRenderer<F extends CellFactory<any>> {
  constructor(
    private factory: F
  ) { }

  getCellByIndex<I extends number>(index: I, element: ElementFinder):
    (F extends CellFactory<infer T> ? T : never)[I] {
    return this.factory.createCellForIndex(index, element);
  }
}
```

Instead of the specific cell type, it just infers the type as `Cell`

```
const renderer = new CellRenderer(cellFactory);
const cell1R = renderer.getCellByIndex(1, new ElementFinder()); // Cell, not specific enough
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/N91D9N)

Comment: I suggest you consider refactoring to [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAK14w) to give a [mre], and then the fix is to do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpnkXw).  TypeScript doesn't support inference from indexed access types (like `T[I]`) to the corresponding object types (like `T`) (see [ms/TS#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126) which never made it into the language) , so if you need `T` preserved then you should have a more direct structural dependence on `T`.  A phantom property (optional prop of type `T`) should do it.

Comment: Does the above fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: So then do I have your permission to [edit] your original code to use the refactored version with the same underlying issue? (and then write up an answer?)

Comment: Great, thanks. I’ll write up an answer as soon as I get to a real computer

Comment: Forgot to mention that it needs to be v4.3.5. I've fixed a minor issue in the CellElementFactory constructor - `private cells: [...{ [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends Cell ? CellConstructor<T[I]> : never }]` - https://tsplay.dev/mbBeBm

Comment: Why the dependency on an older version of TS? The language changes enough that such dependencies get very difficult very quickly.

Comment: I wish it could be updated, but unfortunately it's out of my control